# strcat not working properly in operator overloading

Tags: string, visual-c++, operator-overloading, strcat

I'm practicing operator overloading but I'm not able to put it through correctly. Can any one tell me what wrong I am doing here.

I don't understand why `strcat` is not concatenating two string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Strings
{
    char str[20];
public:
    Strings()
    {
        str[0] = '\0';
    }
    Strings(char *p)
    {
        strcpy_s(str,p);
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout<<str<<endl;
    }
    Strings operator+(Strings &);
};

Strings Strings::operator+(Strings &k)
{
    Strings temp;

    strcpy_s(temp.str,this->str);
    strcat_s(temp.str,k.str);
    return temp;

}

int main()
{
    Strings s1("Hello, "), s2("How are you?"),s3;
    s1.display();
    s2.display();
    s3.display();
    s3 = s1 + s2;
    s2.display();
}
```

The output is:

```
Hello,
How are you?

How are you?
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't displaying the concatenated string; change the last line from:

```
s2.display();
```

to:

```
s3.display();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `s3` is a `null` string when you are trying to disply `s3`

Please look at your question yourself once again

```
    Strings s1("Hello, "), s2("How are you?"),s3;
    s1.display();    // Hello,
    s2.display();    // How are you?
    s3.display();    // '\0'
    s3 = s1 + s2;
    s2.display();    //How are you?

    s3.display();   //Add this line and test your code
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, I was in hurry and couldn't see it properly. thanks all